# Find mathematical art

Tags: discussion

How can I get enough reputation to be able to actually post an answer here?! It seems that I need 10 reputation to answer the one question that I really want to.  I have some awesome answers to the tweetable mathematical art, but I don't know enough about Code Golfing to answer any other questions.

Comment: Answering is the first way to get reputation. You should be able to answer questions on the main site (not meta) immediately. Once your answer gets upvoted you will gain reputation which will give you access to other things.

Comment: Forget it. It will take much much too long.  I can't work stuff like this out: if(i>500&&i<524&&j>300&&j<600||i>400&&i<624&&j>400&&j<424)return 64;     I'll just post on the Reddit thread.

Comment: The page for that question has some tecnical issues due to the enormous amount of pictures on it. If I wait for it to load properly it's OK though. Note that you are allowed to ANSWER but not COMMENT (at least not on others' posts) with minimum reputation.

Comment: But the realissue here is that that particular question is has a very large number of answers already and has been **PROTECTED** to prevent spamming. The vast majority of the questions are not protected. Answer one of those first to get the reputation you need.

Answer (score 4):

If you can code well enough to do tweetable mathematical art, you can participate in the king of the hill challenges.  These get voted on heavily so you can get reputation on this site faster then on others.  That being said if you have nothing to contribute, please don't upset the other challenges with posts that don't contribute.

If you have another stackexchange account with a decent amount of rep, letting the software garnishes you 100 rep on each site.
This rep, however, cannot be used to overcome that 10 rep wall according to commentors below.

10 rep is 2 votes on a question or just 1 upvote on an answer.  This very low ceiling is to prevent people spamming very low quality posts. Prove you have something to contribute anywhere else on this site and you will get that rep quickly.

Comment: Note that the 10 rep needs to be *gained* on the site so the SE association bonus does **not** count towards that required 10 rep.

Comment: Really? Did not know that.

Comment: Yep, been discussed a few times over on the Mother Meta.

Comment: King of the hills can be complicated. The following questions (coincidentally both about forests) may be more to the OP's taste and are fairly popular (though popularity contests and art are not favoured by everyone): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35322/15599 http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35835/15599 . It would be more productive in terms of votes to wait for a new question which has more traffic. Alternatively new users can post their own questions, but they normally lack the experience to specify them well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to answer another question in order to gain the single upvote required to allow you to post to the protected question, I recommend clicking on the [tags](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags) link at the top of the [questions page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and choosing a tag that interests you. Not all questions on the site require golfing skills.

For example, you may find a challenge you would enjoy under [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), or [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), none of which require shortened code.